# Where are the items in the God Gear mod?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods, xbox-one

I've never really been a PC gamer so I've never really used mods. I downloaded to God Gear mod in skyrim for the Xbox One and can't figure out where the items are located. Just wondering if anyone could help me out with this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The equipment is in a chest in Helgen keep. You can go back to Helgen keep after completing the beginning sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Very beginning. First building that you followed your buddy into where he untied your hands. The chest is to the left of the dead guy you took stuff from. Looks small and dwarvin.

Answer (score -2):

It is in the keep next to the dead stormcloak.

Comment: Could you provide more information? Which dead stormcloak? Where is he? What is the name of the keep?